# Assigning an array as a component of another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, assign

I have a 3-d array G with a size that changes in a loop. In Matlab, I first create an empty array `G = []`;
then I create the first element of G from another existing array D with size 256x256, it is simple to do that in matlab as follows

```
  G(:,:,1) = D(:,:)
```

How can I do the same thing in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Consider preallocating.

In python's numpy you can preallocate like this:

```
G = np.zeros([depth, height, width])
```

then you can [slice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) G in a way similar to matlab, and substitue matrices in it. If you still want to have an array of changing size, you can create a list with your 2D arrays and then convert it to a `np.array`, like so:

```
G = list()
for i in range(N):
    G.append(D)
G = np.array(G)
```

Answer (score 0):

an empty 3d array should look something like this

```
    n = 256
    threeD = [[[0 for k in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)] for i in xrange(n)]
```

or if you want just one 256x256 2d array in the larger 3d array (which is what i think you are trying in Matlab)

```
    threeD = [[[0 for k in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]]
```

where n is the size of each "dimension".

it will give you an array full of 0, or you can replace 0 with None if that is more desirable as an empty array

also, it isn't really an "array" in python, it's a "list"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
G[:,:,1]=D[:,:]
```

Example:

```
>>> G=np.zeros((2,2,2))
>>> D=np.ones((2,2))
>>> G[:,:,1]=D[:,:]
>>> G
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.]]])
```